# Improve MySQL searches on huge tables

Tags: mysql

How to deal with thousands of tuples in a table? How can be searching improved if there is no primary key in my table?

ex:

```
id    attr
1     I'm
1     Too
1     Damn
2     Slow
2     To
2     Search
```

I can group the data together using `group_concat()` but i'm unsure that will it search my complete table to get the end result? And if yes, then how it can be improved?

Comment: Can you post your table structure with indexes creation? If any...

Comment: I don't have indexes. How can i create one on table like this? The only indexes i know are the keys that can be created.

Comment: and why not appending a primary key? it doesn't make things faster but it's for manage

Comment: what is the use of that when i only require these 2 columns in the table? and i was thinkng sort of id->attrib way to create this table. Will primary key prove to be a plus point to implement on this?

Comment: How do you plan to do the searching?

Comment: select id, group_concat(attribute)
from table t
group by id;  maybe?

Comment: Without any indexes all searches through the table will have to be linear scans. To provide any decent help we will need to know more exactly how you're using the table. If it is just the `SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(attribute) FROM table t GROUP BY id` then a simple index on `id` should speed up things.

Comment: This query will have a specific id to get the attributes of. So, can index improve this? And if yes, then how? And do i need to have a primary key for implementing index?

Comment: What query do you actually need to run on the the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `index` on `column` you want to use in `search query` to improve search.

e.g if your table is `CREATE TABLE T1(A INT PRIMARY KEY, B INT, C CHAR(1));`
then index can create using this on `column B`, `CREATE INDEX B ON T1 (B)`;

Comment: Do i need to have a primary key? And what kind of index does this query applies.. Sparse, Dense or Hashes?

Comment: No you don't need primary key. Type of index depend on storage engine. More you can read here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html